# optimizing nested select sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, query-performance

I was wondering what is the best performance implementation of this query:

```
select subscriber 
from DEGREE
where sub_type is null 
 and (subscriber like '91_9%' 
      or SUBSCRIBER like '919%' 
      or (SUBSCRIBER not in (select msisdn from MCI)))
```

FYI MCI table has around 50m records with defined index on msisdn and DEGREE table has index on subscriber.

Best regards.

Comment: How many rows does table DEGREE have? And how many of those have sub_type NULL and how many rows does the query return?

Comment: Table degree has around 2 m records. around 1m of them have sub_typ= null and the query should return around 700k records.

Comment: And how does the current explain plan look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
select d.subscriber 
from DEGREE d
where d.sub_type is null and
      (d.subscriber like '91_9%' or
       d.subscriber like '919%' or
       not exists (select 1 from MCI where MCI.msisdn = d.subscriber)
      );
```

Then create indexes on `degree(sub_type, subscriber)` and `MCI(msisdn)`.

EDIT:

The index on `degree` should cause the following to happen.  Instead of a full table scan on `DEGREE`, the query will do an index scan on the index.  I'm not sure if Oracle is smart enough to use the index for `like` conditions connected by `or`, but at least this is a covering index for the query.

The index on `MCI` should then result in a simple index lookup.

So, with these two indexes, only index operations will be needed to satisfy the query.  That should have a significant impact on performance.

Comment: This rewrite is possible. But can you explain why he should rewrite his query and why the indexes will help him?

Comment: @RobvanWijk Unless the query optimizer is smart enough to do it for you, a `WHERE NOT EXISTS()` is going to outperform a `NOT IN ()`. Also, it simply is easier to read IMHO.

Comment: @RobvanWijk . . . I added in an explanation.

Comment: @deroby if that's always the case, why would Oracle have added the NOT IN clause to its vocabulary?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for adding the explanation. Selecting 1M rows out of a 2M row table isn't likely going to benefit from an index scan. Hopefully the optimizer will prevent using this index. The second index on MCI likely helps if the table contains more than 1 column.

Comment: @RobvanWijk . . . Oracle doesn't set the SQL standard.

Comment: @deroby proof that NOT IN can be faster, just as fast or slower than NOT EXISTS: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074#tom1525158235153

Comment: @RobvanWijk All-right, if you're so adamant on defending `NOT IN()` I'll reword : In my 10+ years of experience I'm tempted to conclude that `WHERE NOT EXISTS()` will outperform `NOT IN()` in most of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
select subscriber 
from DEGREE left outer join MCI on DEGREE.SUBSCRIBER=MCI.msisdn 
where sub_type is null 
 and (subscriber like '91_9%' 
      or SUBSCRIBER like '919%' 
      or MCI.msisdn is null)
```

Comment: It works but i dont get what is the role of MCI.msisdn is null?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN means we need all rows from DEGREE table and matching rows in the joined one. If no match found null is set for all columns of the second table. Thus **MCI.msisdn is null** means skip rows without matching in MCI.

Comment: Are you sure it return right answer? left outer join would return rows  from degree that are match condition in MCI table. But I want rows that are not match in MCI tables.

Comment: You can run both queries and compare results

Comment: same result but Gordon answer was much faster (around 6 times faster)

Comment: added +1 to Gordon's answer